# How would I save changes to a model in SystemModeler?

Tags: system-modeler

How would I save changes to a model in SystemModeler?  The "File | Save" does not save any changes past the initial model creation.

So far, the only way that I can save changes is to create a new model from scratch, followed by a "File | Save" Is it possible to make edits to an existing model and save these?

Comment: i'm not sure the question relates to the topic, but could you specify what you're doing and the version of the WSM?

Comment: As a developer of WSM at Wolfram, I would also like to know in which version and platform you are seeing this. We have not been able to reproduce this in any configuration. File -> Save should save whatever is open in the class window (the big window with the diagram/icon/text views).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if I right-click my own class (under User Classes in the Class Browser), edits may be saved.  The File|Save only works when a user class is selected.

- When a user class is simply open and visible, but not selected in the Class Browser, File|Save will not save any changes.